# Python ftp.nlst() return empty list when where are (sub)directories on the server

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, ftplib

My application needs to download all the directories from a remote FTP, I'm testing for the first time the Python's `ftplib`.

When I try to list all the directories in the remote FTP with the command `ftp.nlst()` it return an empty list. I know for sure that the directory is not empty because this command: `ftp.retrlines('list')` returned an object displaying the names of the subfolders inside the directory.

While I was testing I tried other commands like `ftp.cwd('/other-dir/')` or `ftp.pwd()`, but none of these seems to work.

This is the code that I'm using to display the list of subdirectories:

```
from ftplib import FTP

def ftpConnection():
    ftp = FTP('ftp-address')
    ftp.login('user', 'password') 
    lista = ftp.nlst()
    return (lista)

print(ftpConnection())
```

Output:

```
[]
```

As you can see the list is empty.

---

This is my code for `retrlines`:

```
def ftpConnection():
    ftp = FTP('remoteFtp')
    ftp.login('user', 'password') 
    ftp.retrlines('LIST')

print (ftpConnection())
```

Output:

```
drw-rw-rwx 1          512 Jun 29 09:23 .
drw-rw-rwx 1          512 Jun 28 05:11 103367
drw-rw-rwx 1          512 Jun 29 02:01 121901
drw-rw-rwx 1          512 Sep 23  2016 123233
drw-rw-rwx 1          512 Jun 29 09:19 125183
drw-rw-rwx 1          512 Jun 29 02:34 133028
```

---

This is the output from command-line `ftp`:

```
230-Welcome clt_kantar_italy from remoteFtp. You are now logged in to the server.
230 User logged in, proceed.
```

```
ftp> dir
200 PORT command successful.
150 File status okay; about to open data connection.
drw-rw-rwx 1          512 Jun 29 09:23 .
drw-rw-rwx 1         512 Jun 28 05:11 103367
drw-rw-rwx 1          512 Jun 29 02:01 121901
drw-rw-rwx 1          512 Sep 23  2016 123233
drw-rw-rwx 1          512 Jun 29 09:19 125183
drw-rw-rwx 1          512 Jun 29 02:34 133028
226 Closing data connection. Transferred 481 bytes.
ftp: 484 bytes received in 0.01secondi 37.23Kbyte/sec)
```

```
ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful.
150 File status okay; about to open data connection.
226 Closing data connection. Transferred 0 bytes.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you see it yourself with `ftp` (from the behavior I assume it's Windows `ftp.exe`).

- `dir` command, which uses `LIST` FTP command, returns the folders;
- `ls` command, which uses `NLST` FTP command, does not return the folders.

---

So it's how *your* FTP server behaves – It does not return folders in `NLST`.

If you need to retrieve folders from *your* FTP server, you have to use `LIST`:

- either use [`FTP.dir` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.dir)
- or [`FTP.retrlines('LIST')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrlines).